# Scrapy how to scrape all the text under an element, no matter how deeply nested the children containing the text are?

Tags: css-selectors, scrapy

```
<div class="content">
    // no fixed html formatting, but i want all the text for all the children here even nested children!
</div>
```

So how do i go about doing this, i only know one fixed element but under it, the HTML elements are very inconsistent from page to page, sometimes the text i want is directly in paragraphs under the fixed div, or sometimes it's under many nested divs but i want a method to extract the text under div.content no matter how the children are arranged.